How to Efficiently Extract NDVI Values from Large Xarray Datasets for Multiple Polygons Using Dask?
I work with large satellite datasets (50-500 GB) in xarray, which include NDVI values. My goal is to extract NDVI values from about 3000 polygons and their surrounding buffer areas. For each time point in the xarray dataset, I need to extract two NDVI values: one for the polygon and one for the buffer zone. The extraction involves filtering the time series early for qualitatively usable points using the scene classification layer to check for clouds. Additionally, I average only those NDVI pixel values in the buffer that are classified as vegetation. I use xarray, numpy, and dask for this process.
However, I am struggling with performance. The process is very slow, and using dask.delayed made it worse. On my HPC, I received warnings that 90GB per worker was insufficient for processing even 5 small geometries. Here is a simplified version of my current approach, which I call while iterating over the rows of my shapefile (though I know this isn't optimal):
def extract_ndvi_values(ann, xds, ann_gdf_crs):
    clipped_xds = xds.rio.clip([ann.geometry], crs=ann_gdf_crs, all_touched=True, drop=True, from_disk=True)
    time_mask = get_time_mask(clipped_xds, valid_scl_keys=[4, 5, 6])
    ann_ndvi = clipped_xds["NDVI"].sel(time=time_mask).mean(dim=("x", "y"))
    ann_geom_buffer = create_differential_buffer(ann.geometry, large_buffer_size=200, small_buffer_size=10)
    clipped_buffer_xds = xds.rio.clip([ann_geom_buffer], crs=ann_gdf_crs, all_touched=True, drop=True, from_disk=True)
    ann_scl_buffer = clipped_buffer_xds["SCL"].sel(time=time_mask)
    ann_ndvi_buffer = clipped_buffer_xds["NDVI"].sel(time=time_mask).where(ann_scl_buffer == 4).mean(dim=("x", "y"), skipna=True)
    return pd.DataFrame({"NDVI": ann_ndvi, "NDVI_UNDIST": ann_ndvi_buffer}, index=ann_ndvi.time)

tasks = []
for idx, ann in ann_gdf.iterrows():
    print(f"Processing {ann["id"]}...")
    delayed_obj = dask.delayed(extract_ndvi_values)(ann, self.data, ann_gdf.crs)
    tasks.append(delayed_obj)

with ProgressBar():
    results = dask.compute(*tasks)

I need help improving scaling and performance while retaining xarray and dask.

Didn't have an answer, but it looks like a great question to ask to https://discourse.pangeo.io/
